# Are there any pictures of Iridium flares from the ISS?

Tags: iss, iridium, satellite-flare

As the title states, are there any pictures of Iridium flares from the ISS?

Related:

- [How much longer will we be able to see Iridium satellite flares?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21165/26446)

Comment: slightly related [What goes into an Iridium Flare prediction model besides the ephemerides?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21184/12102)